# i am solving a question related to bfs traversal and there i got this doubt so can anyone plz solves this doubt?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

if a BFS is applied on a graph is it necessary that the resultant BFS tree contains all the edges that are in the original graph ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can check how the BFS algorithm works: if an edge $(u,v)$ is examined and $v$ has already been discovered, then $(u,v)$ won't be in the BFS tree.

Besides, as the name suggests, a BFS tree is a tree (and hence acyclic). This means that a BFS on a graph that is cyclic cannot possibly contain all graph edges. Try running a BFS by hand on a triangle graph (i.e., a cycle on $3$ vertices).